# How to create a Popup login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Visual Studio, I've created a default MVC app with login.

I would now like to change the login so that instead of going to a page, it appears as a popup.

The reason for this is that the user will be part way through the checkout steps, and I don't want to lose the position or state.

Is there an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video tutorial I found: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RokXgBFSvp8

And a non video version illustrating similar thing: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315535/How-to-render-MVC-View-on-a-Modal-Popup-Window

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery load function...

Here is the modal body

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="login-div"></div>
</div>
```

here is the jQuery which has the login form id "#loginFor"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login-div').load('/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=WhereYouWanttoGo #loginForm');
    });
```